# Autenticação em rotas API do laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api

Estou realizando uns testes na construção de uma *API* com o Laravel. No momento todas as *URLS* da *API* estão com acesso sem autenticação. Estou tentando permitir após autenticação do usuário.

Em routes/api.php estou definindo:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Auth::routes();
Route::get('/member/{id}', 'PessoaController@edit')->middleware('auth:api');
```

E no meu controller está definido dessa forma:

```
<?php

  namespace App\Http\Controllers;

  use App\Pessoa;
  use JsValidator;
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
  use Illuminate\Http\Request;
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
  use App\Http\Requests\PessoaRequest;

  date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

   class PessoaController extends Controller
 {

public function __construct(Pessoa $pessoa)
{
    $this->Pessoa = $pessoa;
    $this->middleware('auth.api')->except(['index', 'show']);
    $this->middleware('auth.api:optional')->only(['index', 'show']);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Por que definir outra APi dentro de Routes?
Veja como eu faço.

Dentro do routes.php

```
Route::resource('pessoas', 'PessoasController');
```

E dentro do controller

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth', ['only' => ['index']]); // exigir permissão para acessar
}
```